# Can I add HTML tags to the email subject using JavaMail API?

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, html-email

I want to add the "white-space:nowrap" CSS property for certain two words in my email subject using [JavaMail API](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/).

Here is my code:

```
String str = "These <span style='white-space: nowrap'>Two words</span>";
mail.setSubject(str, "UTF-8");
```

But when I view in email client, subject has been displayed as *text*, not in HTML format.

```
These <span style='white-space: nowrap'>Two words</span>
```

Please let me know what could be the problem.

Comment: As i know the subject is only text and can not be formated

Comment: but i have seen some mails from a blog where they are adding emoticons in the subject , i inspected it , They have achieved by adding the image tag. wondering how they had achieved this.

Comment: I suppose that is the mail client app who renders the image or the style of the subject. For example you can try this in gmail  =?utf-8?Q?=F3=BE=93=B4?=

Comment: Differents apps uses differents encodings

Comment: so we cannot add the html tags in mail subject using java mail api, am i correct @MarcoA.Hernandez.

Comment: Well the subject field only accept text, but if you know the way that your mail app encodes images or formats you could use it. As I said if you use mail.setSubject("=?utf-8?Q?=F3=BE=93=B4?="); you should get an image when open the mail with gmail, but not when open with another program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML is not possible in the subject.
You might try a **hard-space**, also called *non-breaking space*, U+00A0.

```
String str = "These Two\u00A0words";
mail.setSubject(str ,"UTF-8");
```